# Arrays cutoff in multicol - 2 columns

Tags: errors, compiling, multicol, arrays

**The Problem**

Hey, I spent about 3 hours trying to solve this problem with `multicol` in LaTeX. Hope it would help some people out: [arrays cuttoff in LaTeX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9SnH.png)

So as you could see, my arrays in the `\align*` environment are cut off in the `multicol` environment that looked fine in the `\align*` environment: [Arrays in an `align*` environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ACp5.png)

Here's my code:

`\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` without cut off:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{header}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{9}{5} & 0 & \frac{111}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{$R_3-\frac{9}{5}R_1$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{216}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{$R_3-R_1$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{206}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{Normalizing $R_3$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{412}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{$R_2-R_3$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{402}{5} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{412}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{$R_1+\frac{5}{6}R_3$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{171}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{402}{5} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{412}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{Rearranging into Row Echelon Form} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{402}{5} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{171}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{412}{5}
\end{array}\right] \\ 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

`\multicol` with the cut off:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{header}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{multicol}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\setlength{\columnsep}{0cm} 
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicol*}{2}
\begin{align*} 
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{9}{5} & 0 & \frac{111}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{$R_3-\frac{9}{5}R_1$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{216}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{$R_3-R_1$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{206}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{Normalizing $R_3$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{412}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{$R_2-R_3$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{402}{5} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{412}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{$R_1+\frac{5}{6}R_3$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{171}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{402}{5} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{412}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{Rearranging into Row Echelon Form} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{402}{5} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{171}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{412}{5}
\end{array}\right] \\ 
\end{align*}

\end{multicol*}

\end{document}
```

**The Solution**

If your compiled LaTeX solution is to split up the long `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` into a few`\begin{align*}...\end{align*}' so you have something like:

```
\begin{multicol}{2}
...
\begin{align*}...\end{align*}
\begin{align*}...\end{align*}
\begin{align*}...\end{align*}
...
\end{multicol}
```

So, correct code:

```
\begin{multicol*}{2}
\begin{align*}
\text{Simplifying} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{9}{5} & 0 & \frac{111}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{$R_3-\frac{9}{5}R_1$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{216}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\text{$R_3-R_1$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{206}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{Normalizing $R_3$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{412}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{$R_2-R_3$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{6} & -\frac{35}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{402}{5} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{412}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\text{$R_1+\frac{5}{6}R_3$} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{171}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{402}{5} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{412}{5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
\text{Rearranging into Row Echelon Form} \\
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 19 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{402}{5} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{171}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{412}{5}
\end{array}\right] \\ 
\end{align*}

\end{multicols*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is the problem?

Comment: Please do not post solutions into the question box it breaks the question and answer format of the site and makes it impossible for anyone to post an answer.

Comment: you should not be using `align*` at all here as there is no alignment (`&`) specified.

Comment: You **can** answer your own question, although you might wait a day or two to see if anyone has a better solution.

Comment: good points, the align* environment is unnecessary — one could simply use the align environment — that is the correct choice. Thank you @David Carlisle

Comment: @MishaLubich No. There is no alignment so `align` is also wrong, the difference between `align` and `align*` is whether you want the formula to be numbered, there is no difference in the alignment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right, would a \[ \] environment be appropriate? I used \align to ensure that the matrices are vertically aligned.

Comment: Note that this is the _question_ post there should be no solution here at all, you can post an answer in an answer post if you wish (but it isn't really clear what your question is)